# Definitions are not distributed to parallel kernels

Tags: bugs, parallelization

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.0.2.**

---

I have a small package with utilities, which looks like that:

```
BeginPackage["Utilities`"];
f::usage = "...";
Begin["`Private`"];
f[x_] := x;
End[];
EndPackage[];
DistributeDefinitions["Utilities`"];
```

When I load this package and try to use my function `f` with `ParallelEvaluate`, everything works as expected:

```
(* Input *)
ParallelEvaluate[{$KernelID, f[2]}]
(* Output *)
{{1, 2}, {2, 2}}
```

But I get into trouble when I try to use `Utilities` package inside another.

```
BeginPackage["MainPackage`", {"Utilities`"}];
g::usage = "...";
Begin["`Private`"];
g[x_] := ...;
End[];
EndPackage[];
```

The function `g` is quite big and complicated and `f` is called somewhere inside it.

When I call `g`, everything works fine. But when I try to do something like this:

```
ParallelEvaluate[{$KernelID, g[2]}]
```

I get a lot of errors. As I understood, the problem is in function f. It seems to be not defined in the context of the main package for parallel kernels.

I've added `Print[Definition[f]];` into the body of `g`, and when I try to use `ParallelEvaluate` with `g` I get this:

[image: Both kernels print Null.]

Which means, that `f` isn't defined inside of `g`. Do you have any ideas, how I can fix it?

---

**Update 1.**

While manual distribution of definitions doesn't work, `ParallelNeeds` works good. I removed `DistributeDefinitions` from `Utilities` package and added `ParallelNeeds` to `MainPackage`:

```
ParallelNeeds["Utilities`"];
BeginPackage["MainPackage`", {"Utilities`"}];
...
EndPackage[];
DistributeDefinitions["MainPackage`"];
```

This work fine. But in my case Utilities package is stored in another folder. And if I do so in `MainPackage`:

```
SetDirectory["Dependencies/"]; (* Directory with Utilities package. *)

ParallelNeeds["Utilities`"];
BeginPackage["MainPackage`", {"Utilities`"}];
...
EndPackage[];
DistributeDefinitions["MainPackage`"];

ResetDirectory[];
```

The definition is again not distributed. It seems like changing directory "erases" distributed definitions. Can I avoid it somehow without placing `Utilities` near `MainPackage`?

---

**Update 2.**

I found a solution for the problem on my own. One need to set/reset directories not only for kernel, but also for its subkernels, like this:

```
SetDirectory["some_dir"];
ParallelEvaluate[SetDirectory["some_dir"]];
```

**Update 3.**

It's a **bug**. The answer of Wolfram support:

> I could reproduce this problem on my machine and have now reported it to our developers. I hope this can be fixed in our future releases. We at Wolfram, appreciate your feedback and encourage you to let us know of any other problem you may come across while using Mathematica.

Comment: Could you report this to Wolfram support and tell us what they said?  In version 9 the definitions do get distributed properly.

Comment: Maybe related to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72930/1364) question?

Comment: Does anyone know if this has been fixed? If so, in which version?

Comment: If anyone has more up-to-date information about this bug, please update the bug header (see http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1610/standard-header-for-bugs-tagged-posts-for-easy-searching).

Comment: @MichaelE2, I don't encounter this issue in version 10.0.2, so I've updated the bug header. But the bug could be probably fixed in the previous release.

Comment: @Melkogotto Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this may be a bug in version 10 as in version 9.0.1 the definition *does* get distributed.  What happens in version 10 also directly contradicts the documentation.  Here's an illustration:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I've reported to Wolfram support and now wait for their answer. Can you help me with another problem, which I've described in the update of my question?