# Why doesn't my expression evaluate at the subkernel?

Tags: bugs, evaluation, parallelization

Consider this code:

```
BeginPackage["Test`"];
f1::usage = "";
f2::usage = "";
f3::usage = "";
Begin["`Private`"];
fQ[myf_] := Head[myf] === f1;
f1[n_][t_] := 0;
f2[myf1_?fQ, myf2_?fQ][t_] := 0;
f3[myf1_] := myf1[0.];
End[];
EndPackage[];
```

The expression evaluate on main kernel

```
f3[f2[f1[1], f1[1]]]
(*0*)
```

but when I evaluate on subkernels, it seems that it is not evaluated

```
LaunchKernels[];
DistributeDefinitions[f1, f2, f3];

ParallelEvaluate[Block[{data}, data = f3[f2[f1[1], f1[1]]];
  Print[data];], (Kernels[])[[1]]]

(* (kernel 1) Test`f2[Test`f1[1],Test`f1[1]][0.]*)
```

Where do I do wrong?

And if I distribute the definition of the `fQ`, it then get evaluated:

```
DistributeDefinitions[f1, f2, f3, Test`Private`fQ];
ParallelEvaluate[Block[{data}, data = f3[f2[f1[1], f1[1]]];
  Print[data]], (Kernels[])[[1]]]
(*  (kernel 1) 0 *)
```

How should I understand this behavior?

Comment: Somebody more knowledgeable than me will probably have a better answer, but it looks as though the parameter testing for f2 needs to call fQ, and that function definition isn't automatically distributed to the other kernels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @image_doctor notes in a comment, the problem occurs because the definition of `` Test`Private`fQ `` is not being distributed to the other kernels.

`DistributeDefinitions` uses `` Language`ExtendedFullDefinition `` to determine which definitions to transmit.  We can see this by evaluating the following expression:

```
On[Language`ExtendedFullDefinition]
DistributeDefinitions[f1, f2, f3];
Off[]

(* ...
   Language`ExtendedFullDefinition::trace :
   Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[{f1,f2,f3},ExcludedContexts->{Algebra,...}] -->
   Language`DefinitionList[
      f1->{...,SubValues->{HoldPattern[f1[<<1>>][<<1>>]]:>0},...},
      f2->{...,SubValues->{HoldPattern[f2[<<2>>][<<1>>]]:>0},...},
      f3->{...,DownValues->{HoldPattern[f3[<<1>>]]:>Test`Private`myf1[0.]},...}]. >>
*)
```

`` Test`Private`fQ `` is absent from the generated `` Language`DefinitionList ``.

`` Language`ExtendedFullDefinition `` is normally able to trace all dependencies in a function:

```
ff[x_] := gg[x]
gg[x_] := x + 1
Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[ff]

(*
   Language`DefinitionList[
     ff->{...,DownValues->{HoldPattern[ff[x_]]:>gg[x]},...},
     gg->{...,DownValues->{HoldPattern[gg[x_]]:>x+1},...}
   ]
*)
```

But apparently it does not account for pattern tests in definitions:

```
ff2[x_?gg2] := 1
gg2[x_] := True
Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[ff2]

(*
   Language`DefinitionList[
     ff2->{...,DownValues->{HoldPattern[ff2[x_?gg2]]:>1},NValues->{},...}
   ]
*)
```

The pattern test function `gg2` is missed by the dependency scan.  This would appear to be a bug, but I might just be unaware of some compelling reason to ignore pattern tests in these circumstances.

As noted in the question, the work-around is to manually identify and distribute any missing dependencies.  The "distribute" part of that is easy -- it is the "identify" part that can be difficult.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It appears to me like a bug too. Otherwise, one have to manually distribute all the private definitions. I have reported as a bug to technical support.